# Cocos2d-x - Crashing on CCLabelBMFont loading

Tags: fonts, cocos2d-x

I am trying to load via the cocos2d-x method:

```
CCLabelBMFont* newLabel = CCLabelBMFont::create("Test string", "font/ComicBook.fnt");
newLabel->setPosition(CCPoint(m_screenSize.width / 2.0f, m_screenSize.height / 2.0f));
addChild(newLabel, 12);
```

It's crashing on the first line where it creates the font.

A stack trace reveals that it can find the font file but it crashes here:

```
bool CCTexture2D::hasPremultipliedAlpha()
{
    return m_bHasPremultipliedAlpha;
}
```

I am not sure what this means. Thank you.

Comment: is `font/ComicBook.fnt` in your resources for the project?

Comment: @GameDeveloper Yes. It finds the file. It also throws a different error if I rename the file explaining that it can't be found. So that's not the issue.

Comment: @SatchmoBrown Have you found the solution

Answer (score 0):

Use text fnt format and not xml.